# Ruby (not Rails) attribute validation, saving records and output

Tags: ruby

I am implementing **Game of Life in Ruby** and here is what I have so far:

```
class Cell

  attr_accessor :world, :x, :y

  def initialize(world=World.new, x=0, y=0)
    @world = world
    @world.cells << self
    @x = x
    @y = y
  end

  def neighbours
    @neighbours = []
    world.cells.each do |cell|

      # Detects neighbour to the north
      if self.x == cell.x && self.y == cell.y - 1
        @neighbours << cell
      end
      # Detects neighbour to the north-east
      if self.x == cell.x - 1 && self.y == cell.y - 1
        @neighbours << cell
      end
      # Detects neighbour to the east
      if self.x == cell.x - 1 && self.y == cell.y
        @neighbours << cell
      end
      # Detects neighbour to the south-east
      if self.x == cell.x - 1 && self.y == cell.y + 1
        @neighbours << cell
      end
      # Detects neighbour to the south
      if self.x == cell.x && self.y == cell.y + 1
        @neighbours << cell
      end
      # Detects neighbour to the south-west
      if self.x == cell.x + 1 && self.y == cell.y + 1
        @neighbours << cell
      end
      # Detects neighbour to the west
      if self.x == cell.x + 1 && self.y == cell.y
        @neighbours << cell
      end
      # Detects neighbour to the north-west
      if self.x == cell.x + 1 && self.y == cell.y - 1
        @neighbours << cell
      end

    end
    @neighbours
  end

  def alive?
    self.world.cells.include?(self)
  end

  def dead?
    !self.world.cells.include?(self)
  end

  def die!
    self.world.cells.delete(self)
  end

  def revive!
    self.world.cells << self
  end

end

class World
  attr_accessor :cells

  def initialize
    @cells = []
  end

  def tick!
    self.cells.each do |cell|
      # Rule 1
      if cell.neighbours.count < 2
        cell.die!
      end
    end
  end

end
```

I have been coding in Rails for a while but **I am confused as to how to do the following things:**

1. validate and make sure only one Cell object can exist on one field in the World?
2. How to save things to DB (postgresql for example) ? And do I have to in this case or can I just leave it as it and run it in memory?
3. How to make the graphical output of my Game of life so it looks something like this?

[image: Game of life gif]

Reason for my confusion is because Rails does this right out of the box and now I just need the help of understanding how Ruby alone does this.

EDIT:

I've updated the Cell class with validation method, but I can only run it after the object is being initialized. Is there a way to run it while initializing? Here's the code:

```
  5   def initialize(world=World.new, x=0, y=0)                                                           | 53       neighbour_cell = Cell.new(subject.world, -1, 0)                                                 
  6     @world = world                                                                                    | 54       subject.neighbours.count.should == 1                                                            
  7     @world.cells << self # if self.valid? < this after if doesn't work                                         | 55     end                                                                                               
  8     @x = x                                                                                            | 56                                                                                                       
  9     @y = y                                                                                            | 57     it 'Detects cell to the north-west' do                                                            
 10   end                                                                                                 | 58       neighbour_cell = Cell.new(subject.world, -1, 1)                                                 
 11                                                                                                       | 59       subject.neighbours.count.should == 1                                                            
 12   def valid?                                                                                          | 60     end                                                                                               
 13     @valid = true                                                                                     | 61                                                                                                       
 14     self.world.cells.each do |cell|                                                                   | 62     it 'Creates a live cell' do                                                                       
 15       if self.x == cell.x && self.y == cell.y                                                         | 63       cell.should be_alive                                                                            
 16         @valid = false                                                                                | 64     end                                                                                               
 17         self.world.cells.delete(self)                                                                 | 65                                                                                                       
 18       end                                                                                             | 66     it 'Kills a cell' do                                                                              
 19     end                                                                                               | 67       cell.die!                                                                                       
 20     @valid                                                                                            | 68       cell.should be_dead                                                                             
 21   end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it! But not with the approach taken here. Here is my code below, the only thing left to do is implement some graphic output. Also, [here is the whole code on Github](https://github.com/ofcan/game-of-life-ruby), check it out and comment and help me improve it and stuff. Thank you both for helping me :)

I could refactor this 'live_neighbours_around_cell(cell)' method, but don't know how. Can you help with that? Also, it would be useful to add 'Cell.new' immediately to 'cells' array and not like I do now where I have separate function for that.

```
class Game
  attr_accessor :world

  def initialize(world=World.new, seeds=[[1, 1]])
    @world = world
    seeds.each do |seed|
      world.cell_board[seed[0]][seed[1]].alive = true
    end
  end

  def tick!
    next_round_live_cells = []
    next_round_dead_cells = []

    world.cells.each do |cell|
      # Rule 1: 
      # Any live cell with fewer than two live neighbours dies
      if world.live_neighbours_around_cell(cell).count < 2
        next_round_dead_cells << cell
      end
      # Rule 2:
      # Any live cell with two or three live neighbours lives on to the next generation
      if cell.alive? && world.live_neighbours_around_cell(cell).count == (2 || 3)
        next_round_live_cells << cell
      end
      # Rule 3:
      # Any live cell with more than three live neighbours dies
      if cell.alive? && world.live_neighbours_around_cell(cell).count > 3
        next_round_dead_cells << cell
      end
      # Rule 4:
      # Any dead cell with exactly three live neighbours becomes a live cell
      if cell.dead? && world.live_neighbours_around_cell(cell).count == 3
        next_round_live_cells << cell
      end
    end

    next_round_live_cells.each do |cell|
      cell.revive!
    end
    next_round_dead_cells.each do |cell|
      cell.die!
    end
  end
end

class World
  attr_accessor :rows, :cols, :cell_board, :cells

  # Scheme of default initialized world matrix
  #------------------------
  #     0     1     2
  # 0 [ dead, dead, dead ]
  # 1 [ dead, alive, dead ]
  # 2 [ dead, dead, dead ]
  #-----------------------

  def initialize(rows=3, cols=3)
    @rows = rows
    @cols = cols
    @cells = []

    @cell_board = Array.new(rows) do |row|
      Array.new(cols) do |col|
        Cell.new(row, col)
      end
    end

    cell_board.each do |row|
      row.each do |element|
        if element.is_a?(Cell)
          cells << element
        end
      end
    end
  end

  def live_cells
    cells.select { |cell| cell.alive }
  end

  def live_neighbours_around_cell(cell)
    live_neighbours = []
    live_cells.each do |live_cell|
      # Neighbour to the North
      if live_cell.x == cell.x - 1 && live_cell.y == cell.y
        live_neighbours << live_cell
      end
      # Neighbour to the North-East
      if live_cell.x == cell.x - 1 && live_cell.y == cell.y + 1
        live_neighbours << live_cell
      end
      # Neighbour to the East
      if live_cell.x == cell.x && live_cell.y == cell.y + 1
        live_neighbours << live_cell
      end
      # Neighbour to the South-East
      if live_cell.x == cell.x + 1 && live_cell.y == cell.y + 1
        live_neighbours << live_cell
      end
      # Neighbour to the South
      if live_cell.x == cell.x + 1 && live_cell.y == cell.y
        live_neighbours << live_cell
      end
      # Neighbour to the South-West
      if live_cell.x == cell.x + 1 && live_cell.y == cell.y - 1
        live_neighbours << live_cell
      end
      # Neighbour to the West
      if live_cell.x == cell.x && live_cell.y == cell.y - 1
        live_neighbours << live_cell
      end
      # Neighbour to the North-West
      if live_cell.x == cell.x - 1 && live_cell.y == cell.y - 1
        live_neighbours << live_cell
      end
    end
    live_neighbours
  end

end

class Cell
  attr_accessor :x, :y, :alive

  def initialize(x=0, y=0)
    @x = x
    @y = y
    @alive = false
  end

  def alive?
    alive
  end

  def dead?
    !alive
  end

  def die!
    @alive = false
  end

  def revive!
    @alive = true # same as > self.alive = true
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It's good that you're breaking out of Rails and trying something different, especially a classic challenge like the Game of Life.

As for your questions, they all depend on the system design that you choose. But for a simple implementation here's a few pointers.

1. How about using the `Set` class? This is an array of objects that allows no duplicates.
2. You only need a DB if you want to maintain the state between separate runs of the application. If you don't need that, just keep it all in memory.
3. This is too big a question to answer here, but you have many options. The extremes are:

   - managing screen updates pixel rendering yourself, printing characters to the terminal as the cells change
   - using something like [rubygame](http://rubygame.org/), which has a concept of sprites, GUIs and drawing

Comment: Set class is only available in ruby 2.0 as far as I can tell and I use 1.9.3-p125. I know I can update easily but would like to (for practice) to do it without it. Can you explain how?

Answer (score 1):

You are asking some big, general questions here, and each of them have many answers.  I'll give my initial take on each:

**1: Validation** - It seems like (coming from rails) you want to have some kind of method like [`valid?`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#valid-and-invalid) that you can call on your objects.  In pure ruby, though, you have to define explicitly what a "valid" object really is.  You also have to decide where your validation should take place, i.e. *which object is doing the validation and which object is being validated*.

From the code presented above, I'd suggest that you need at least one more class, call it `Game` for example, which controls the world and all of the cells in it.  Currently, you've loaded a lot of logic into the `Cell` class, and you might want to review the [single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) to see if this is a valid (ha ha) design choice.

**2. Persistence** - There's nothing stopping you from using ActiveRecord in pure ruby as your ORM.  You could check out this SO question for an example implementation: [how-to-use-active-record-without-rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11111733/how-to-use-active-record-without-rails).

**3. Graphics** - There are a number of [game libraries](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/game_libraries) for ruby which have built-in graphics APIs for whichever platform you are on.  I've not worked with them much personally, but [gosu](https://github.com/jlnr/gosu) seems like a good option.

Comment: I edited the question with additional code. You mean to add a new class just to validate things? How should that new class interact with Cell and World classes than?